# Comparar e substituir texto em grandes volumes de dados

Tags: c#

Tenho um dicionario de dados com algumas abreviações e preciso percorrer uma lista contendo dezenas e até centenas de paragrafos a fim de comparar as palavras e substitui-las palavras por essas abreviações.

Qual a alternativa (ou melhor maneira) para comparar Strings de grandes volumes de dados sem uso do Replace ?

Comment: É C# ou VB.NET?

Comment: É csharp, to definindo se será web.api ou ws ou wcf

Comment: Olá Adriano. Esse dicionário possui quantas abreviações, aproximadamente?

Comment: Até o momento 300 abreviações

Comment: algum progresso ?

Comment: Olá @Rovann Linhalis, tive que ser direcionado para uma outra atividade e assim que puder vou implementar essa sugestão e fazer alguns testes de performance, assim que retomar eu dou um retorno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nunca fiz algo do tipo, mas, pelo que entendi da sua dúvida, começaria com um código assim:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Dicionario> dicionario = new List<Dicionario>();
            //Carrega o dicionário

            string texto = @"texto gigante aqui
era uma vez, blabla bla";
            string novoTexto = "";
            string[] linhas = texto.Split('\r');

            for (int l = 0; l < linhas.Length;l++)
            {
                string[] palavras = linhas[l].Split(' ');
                for (int p = 0; p < palavras.Length; p++)
                {
                    Dicionario d = dicionario.Find(x => x.Palavra.ToUpper() == palavras[p].ToUpper());
                    if (d != null)
                        palavras[p] = d.Abreviacao;

                    novoTexto += palavras[p] + " ";
                }

                novoTexto += "\r";
            }

            //Seu novo texto
            Console.Write(novoTexto);

        }

        class Dicionario
        {
            public string Palavra { get; set; }
            public string Abreviacao { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

aí passaria a fazer testes de desempenho para tentar melhorar algo e ver se é realmente isso que precisa.

espero ter ajudado

Comment: Vou implementar e fazer uns testes e darei um retorno, abriga